# Is there anyway to connect IBM RTC and Spring tool suite 4 IDE?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ide, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational, spring-tools-4

I have IBM eclipse to load code from RTC, but i'm comfortable with working in STS. If there is any plugin to connect IBM RTC from STS would be great to commit code. I tried all the way, it all suggests for Eclipse IDE. Anyone has any idea about this ?

Comment: The RTC Eclipse client add-on marketplace entry looks rather old and didn't seem to be updated for any recent Eclipse platform versions. I would recommend to ask the RTC team how to install RTC components into the latest Eclipse versions to see if that is even possible and supported.

Comment: @MartinLippert Not sure for the very latest version indeed, but I am using it at work with an Oxygen, and a 3.1.3 RTC plugin compatible with RTC 6.0.x

Comment: Thanks @MartinLippert for your response

Comment: @VonC as you said, i have no issues with connecting Eclipse and RTC. But i want to connect STS and RTC if possible

Comment: I think this highly depends on the versions that the RTC plugin for Eclipse supports (base Eclipse version). Spring Tools 4 ship support for the latest version (2020-03 at the moment) as well as for the previous version (2019-12 at the moment). We don't ship a version of Spring Tools 4 that are compatible with Eclipse Oxygen, in case you need to go back that far in history to get RTC support.

Comment: If you have no issues connecting Eclipse and RTC, then the question is which Eclipse platform version you use for that. If you can tell me, I can look up whether we have a compatible version of the Spring Tools 4 for that version. If so, we could continue to find out whether there is a direct compatibility issue when installing both.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet would be to take a generic Eclipse and add:

- the [RTC Eclipse Client Add-Ons](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rtc-eclipse-client-add-ons)
- the [Spring Tools 4 plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4) (as [described here](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/february/springboot.php))

And see if both can cohabit.

Comment: I will try it and let you know